# Attempt to read property \"view\" on null when sending password reset email

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-8, laravel-authentication

I am trying to build password reset functionality but with a custom email template. So instead of returning the MailMessage from the notification I can sending my own custom mail.

Sending the email is working but the problem is in postman I get a 500 with this error

```
 "message": "Attempt to read property \"view\" on null",
    "exception": "ErrorException",
    "file": "/home/vagrant/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Notifications/Channels/MailChannel.php",
    "line": 92
```

Here is my code

Password reset method in my controller

```
public function sendResetPasswordLink(SendResetPasswordLinkRequest $request)
{
    $status = Password::sendResetLink($request->only('email'));

    if($status == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT) {
        return "work";
    }
}
```

sendPasswordResetNotification method in User model

```
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token) 
{
    \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::info('sendPasswordResetNotification ran');
    $url = $this->clientBaseUrl . '/reset-password/' . $token;

    $this->notify(new ResetPasswordNotification(request('email'), $url));
}
```

toMail method in ResetPasswordNotification class

```
 public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return Mail::to($this->email)->send(new ResetPasswordMail($this->url));
    }
```

Then is the ResetPasswordMail class I simply return the view in the build method

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->markdown('emails.reset-password')->subject('Welcome to Walor!');
}
```

So I am getting an email with this template but in postman I am getting a 500 with the error on the top

Answer (score 0):

replace ResetPasswordNotification code with codes in below

```
return (new ResetPasswordMail())->to($notifiable->email);
```